# How to use if else condition in json file

Tags: json

I want to implement something like this in the JSON file

"data": {
"L1": {
"title": mycondition ? "A1" :"A2",
}
}

Comment: Why would this be useful ? Why couldn't you simply write the value linked to that key, since you know it in advance ? (This sounds like an XY problem to me).

Comment: I have two texts "A1" and "A2" which is fixed just want to render it based on condition

Comment: When you write the JSON (using any language), you know what `L1` contains. Hence, you know if you need to write the value A1 or A2. You don't need any condition mechanism for that.

Comment: I want to switch between A1 and A2 based on certain condition

Comment: _I want to switch between A1 and A2 based on certain condition_, Great ! Do this when you serialize your JSON, not **in** the JSON.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) is purely a data format. It has no execution model, no logic, no operators, etc.

You could describe the condition and the possible results *as data*, but it would still require something else to read and parse the JSON and then execute the condition the data describes.